# Jquery .each() and SetTimeout for a random amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Long story short I am aware why setTimeout does not work inside an .each function, but the case I am trying to get working is a bit more complected.

I have two loops this time, an inner and outer. The actions have to be done in this exact order otherwise the outcome will not be correct, meaning each SetTimeout() must stop everything else. Also the timeout time for each function needs to be random.

```
// First Loop
$('.items').each(function(e) {
// Something to do
setTimeout(function() {
    // Code that does it

    // Something else to do
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Code that does it

        // Second Loop
        $('.inner-items').each(function(e) {
            // Something to do
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Code that does it

                // Something else to do
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Code that does it

                    // Why not a third
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // Code that does it
                    }, Math.random());
                }, Math.random());
            }, Math.random());
        });
    }, Math.random());
}, Math.random());
});
```

Comment: *"meaning each SetTimeout() must stop everything else"* - Except `setTimeout()` doesn't stop anything, let alone everything.

Comment: You're probably looking for a JavaScript [**promise**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises).

Comment: You state `I have two loops this time`. Was there an earlier question that would help give this one more context?

Comment: No, I was just referring to the existence of other questions

Comment: What's the use case for this?  You're trying to do something, but you fail to explain what you are trying to accomplish and why you're trying to do it this way. Context will help us determine the best way to accomplish your goals.

Comment: ^ what I was about to say

Comment: I want to build an resource manager for an online game. "Something to do" will generally refer to clicking on an element or button.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Haven't tested, but the idea would be to start with a wait time of 0, then each time you want to "stop" the function your really just adding a new random number to the wait time so each setTimeout is waiting for all of the time added before it along with the newly added random time.

Also, it's important that in your second loop, you are looping through children of the item your currently iterating over instead of all .inner-items. I added `$(this).find('.inner-items')` to do this.

```js
var waitTime = 0;

// First Loop
$('.items').each(function(e) {

    // add to wait time
    waitTime += Math.random();

    // Something to do
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Code that does it
    }, waitTime);

    // add to wait time
    waitTime += Math.random();

    // Something else to do
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Code that does it
    }, waitTime);

    // Second Loop
    $(this).find('.inner-items').each(function(e) {

        // add to wait time
        waitTime += Math.random();

        // Something to do
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Code that does it
        }, waitTime);

        // add to wait time
        waitTime += Math.random();

        // Something else to do
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Code that does it
        }, waitTime);

        // add to wait time
        waitTime += Math.random();

        // Why not a third
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Code that does it
        }, waitTime);
    });
});
```

### Edit

Just tested and it seems to work. I added a minimum of 500 and 2000 each time it adds to better visualize the events triggering sequentially and at random times.

Also I'm not sure what you meant by *"setTimeout does not work inside an .each function"*. But by using Self-Executing functions, I can get the current item being iterated over and use in a setTimeout.

https://codepen.io/RyanGoree/pen/yXXbNM

Comment: For some reason my setTimeout functions are triggering way to fast (all within 500ms or so). I have waitTime set to add by a constant 700ms each function to test it right now.